# How to get Backbone.Collection from Backbone.LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

Let's suppose I can get from the javascript console the following result:

```
var ls = new Backbone.LocalStorage("items"); 
ls; // {"name":"items","records":["1244f588-be3d-c493-5c86-b2abb997af82"]}
```

how should I get the `Backbone.Collection` from the `Backbone.LocalStorage`?

P.S.:
the collection looks like

```
[
{
"title":"test",
"completed":false,
"order":1,
"id":"1244f588-be3d-c493-5c86-b2abb997af82"
},
{
"title":"test2",
"completed":false,
"order":2,
"id":"8a8658b9-b636-eac3-4c54-03c279a73c2d"
}
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either create an empty collection with `collection.localStorage` set to your `Backbone.LocalStorage` object and fetch it:

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection();
c.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("items");
c.fetch();
console.log(c.pluck('id'));
```

or use `findAll` on your `Backbone.LocalStorage` object to get an array of models in storage:

```
var ls = new Backbone.LocalStorage("items");
console.log(ls.findAll());
```

A Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8pHNG/

Comment: collection.fetch() doesn't executes fail callback when the collection is not there in local storage ..

@nikoshr

Comment: your fiddle is broken . can't play with that